# Problemas con la activación de usuario PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos

Desarrollé un sistema login y signup con `PHP` y `MySQL`, todo bien al momento de registrar al usuario sí lo mete a la base de datos, pero al momento de enviar el EMAIL de confirmación la misma página aparece el error que programé que ocurrió un error desconocido al tratar de enviar el correo.

Además cuando trato de activar el usuario (logré hacer que enviará un correo con el id y token), espero que me puedan ayudar. El proyecto lo tengo funcionando en este link, aún como test.

**Archivo de funciones PHP:**

```
 <?php
    
    function isNull($username, $email, $phone, $password, $con_password,  $fullname, $last_name, $date_user){
        if(strlen(trim($username)) < 1 || strlen(trim($email)) < 1 || strlen(trim($phone)) < 1 || strlen(trim($password)) < 1 || strlen(trim($con_password)) < 1 || strlen(trim($fullname)) < 1 || strlen(trim($last_name)) < 1 || strlen(trim($date_user)) < 1)
        {
            return true;
            } else {
            return false;
        }       
    }
    
    function isEmail($email)
    {
        if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            return true;
            } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    function validaPassword($var1, $var2)
    {
        if (strcmp($var1, $var2) !== 0){
            return false;
            } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    function minMax($min, $max, $valor){
        if(strlen(trim($valor)) < $min)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if(strlen(trim($valor)) > $max)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    function usuarioExiste($username)
    {
        global $mysqli;
        
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $num = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        
        if ($num > 0){
            return true;
            } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    function emailExiste($email)
    {
        global $mysqli;
        
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $num = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        
        if ($num > 0){
            return true;
            } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    function phoneExiste($phone)
    {
        
        global $mysqli;
        
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE phone = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $phone);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $num = $stmt->num_rows;
        $stmt->close();
        
        if ($num > 0){
            return true;
            } else {
            return false;
            
        }
        
    }
    
    function generateToken()
    {
        $gen = md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), false));
        return $gen;
    }
    
    function hashPassword($password)
    {
        $hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        return $hash;
    }
    
    function resultBlock($errors){
        if(count($errors) > 0)
        {
            echo "<br><div id='error' class='alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show shadow' role='alert'>
            <ul>";
            foreach($errors as $error)
            {
                echo "<li>".$error."</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
            echo " <button type='button' class='btn-close' data-bs-dismiss='alert' aria-label='Close'></button>";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
    
    function registraUsuario($username, $email, $phone, $pass_hash, $activo, $token, $fullname, $last_name, $date_user, $user_type){
        
        global $mysqli;
        
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, phone, password, activacion, token, fullname, last_name, date_user, user_type) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssissssi', $username, $email, $phone, $pass_hash, $activo, $token, $fullname, $last_name, $date_user, $user_type);
        
        if ($stmt->execute()){
            return $mysqli->insert_id;
            } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    
    function enviarEmail($email, $fullname, $asunto, $cuerpo){
        
        require_once 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
        require_once 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
        require_once 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
        
        $mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
        try {
            } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Ha ocurrido un error desconocido, ya lo estamos investigando.({$mail->ErrorInfo})";
        }
        
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Host = 'clientes.coposa.tech';
        $mail->Username   = 'no-reply@clientes.coposa.tech';  
        $mail->Password = 'JoseNFMX*1108';
        $mail->Port = 465;
        
        $mail->setFrom('no-reply@clientes.coposa.tech', 'Validador de nuevos clientes | COPOSA');
        $mail->addAddress($email, $fullname);
        
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->Subject = $asunto;
        $mail->Body    = $cuerpo;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        
        if($mail->send())
        return true;
        else
        return false;
        
    }
    
    function validaIdToken($id, $token){
        global $mysqli;
        
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT activacion FROM users WHERE id = ? AND token = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param("is", $id, $token);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
        
        if($rows > 0) {
            $stmt->bind_result($activacion);
            $stmt->fetch();
            
            if($activacion == 1){
                $msg = "<div class='card-body'><div class='alert alert-warning' role='alert'><p class='fs-5'>Esta cuenta ya fue activada anteriormente.</p></div></div>";
                } else {
                if(activarUsuario($id)){
                    $msg = "<div class='card-body'><div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'><p class='fs-5'>Listo, tu cuenta ya se encuentra activa.</p></div></div>";
                    } else {
                    $msg = "<div class='card-body'><div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'><p class='fs-5'>Ha ocurrido un error desconocido al tratar de activar tu cuenta, no te preocupes ya lo estamos investigando y te avisaremos cuando lo resolvamos.</p></div></div>";
                }
            }
            } else {
            $msg = "<div class='card-body'><div class='alert alert-primary' role='alert'><p class='fs-5'>El usuario o correo electrónico no están registrados en nuestra base de datos.<br>Por favor <a href='signup.php'>Regístrate</a></p></div></div>";
        }
        return $msg;
    }
    
    function activarUsuario($id)
    {
        global $mysqli;
        
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET activacion=1 WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        return $result;
        
    }
    
    function isNullLogin($username, $password){
        if(strlen(trim($username)) < 1 || strlen(trim($password)) < 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    function login($username, $password)
    {
        global $mysqli;
        
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, user_type, password FROM users WHERE username = ? || email = ? || phone = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $username, $username, $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $rows = $stmt->num_rows;
        
        if($rows > 0) {
            
            if(isActivo($username)){
                
                $stmt->bind_result($id, $user_type, $passw);
                $stmt->fetch();
                
                $validaPassw = password_verify($password, $passw);
                
                if($validaPassw){
                    
                    lastSession($id);
                    $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $id;
                    $_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] = $user_type;
                    
                    header("location: dashboard.php");
                    } else {
                    
                    $errors = "La contraseña es incorrecta, por favor verifica y vuelve a intentarlo";
                    
                }
                
                } else {
                $errors = "El usuario aún no activa la cuenta a través del correo electrónico.";
            }
            
            } else {
            $errors = "El nombre de usuario o correo electrónico, no están registrados en nuestra base de datos.";
        }
        return $errors;
    }
    
    function lastSession($id)
    {
        global $mysqli;
        
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET last_session=NOW(), token_password='', password_request=1 WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
    }
    
    function isActivo($username)
    {
        global $mysqli;
        
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT activacion FROM users WHERE username = ? || email = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($activacion);
        $stmt->fetch();
        
        if ($activacion == 1)
        {
            return true;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    function generaTokenPass($id)
    {
        global $mysqli;
        
        $token = generateToken();
        
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET token_password=? password_request=1 WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $token, $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        
        return $token;
        
    }
    
    function getValor($campo, $campoWhere, $valor)
    {
        global $mysqli;
        
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT $campo FROM users WHERE $campoWhere = ? LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $valor);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $num = $stmt->num_rows;
        
        if ($num >0)
        {
            $stmt->bind_result($_campo);
            $stmt->fetch();
            return $_campo;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    function getPasswordRequest($id)
    {
        global $mysqli;
        
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT password_request FROM users WHERE id = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($_id);
        $stmt->fetch();
        
        if ($_id == 1)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    
    function verificaTokenPass($id, $token){
        global $mysqli;
        
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT activacion FROM users WHERE id = ? AND token_password = ? AND password_request = 1 LIMIT 1");
        $stmt->bind_param('is', $id, $token);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result();
        $num = $stmt->num_rows;
        
        if ($num >0)
        {
            $stmt->bind_result($_campo);
            $stmt->fetch();
            if($activacion == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        
    }
    
    function cambiaPassword($password, $id, $token){
        
        global $mysqli;
        
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET password = ?, token_password='', password_request=0 WHERE id = ? AND token_password = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('sis', $password, $id, $token_password);
        
        if($stmt->execute()){
            return true;
            } else {
            return false;
        }
        
    }



?>
```

**Archivo Signup.php (Para registrar):**

```
    <?php
    
    require 'conexion.php';
    require 'funcs.php';
    
    $errors = array();
    
    if(!empty($_POST))
    {
        
        $username = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
        $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $phone = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
        $password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
        $con_password = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['con_password']);
        $fullname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['fullname']);
        $last_name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['last_name']);
        $date_user = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['date_user']);
        
        $activo = 0;
        $user_type = 2;
        
        if(isNull($username, $email, $phone, $password, $con_password, $fullname, $last_name, $date_user))
        {
            $errors[] = "Todos los campos son obligatorios";
        }
        
        if(!isEmail($email))
        {
            $errors[] = "Dirección de correo electrónico no válida";
        }
        
        if(!validaPassword($password, $con_password))
        {
            $errors[] = "Las contraseñas no coinciden, por favor, verifica.";
        }
        
        if(usuarioExiste($username))
        {
            $errors[] = "El nombre de usuario $username ya se encuentra registrado";
        }
        
        if(emailExiste($email))
        {
            $errors[] = "El correo electrónico $email ya se encuentra registrado";
        }
        
        if(phoneExiste($phone))
        {
            $errors[] = "El número de teléfono $phone ya se encuentra registrado, por favor intenta con otro número o <a href='login.php'>Accede ahora</a>.";
        }
        
        if(count($errors) == 0)
        {
            
            $pass_hash = hashPassword($password);
            $token = generateToken();
            
            $registro = registraUsuario($username, $email, $phone, $pass_hash, $activo, $token, $fullname, $last_name, $date_user, $user_type);
            
            if($registro > 0 )
            {
                
                $url = 'https://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].'/test/activate.php?id='.$registro.'&code='.$token;
            
            $asunto = "Activación necesaria - Activa tu cuenta de COPOSA";
            $cuerpo = "<html><body>";
            $cuerpo .= "    <h3>¡Hola $fullname , gracias por registrarte!</h3><br>";
            $cuerpo .= "    <p>Ahora sólo falta confirmar tu correo electrónico para poder activar de manera correcta tu cuenta, no te preocupes sólo tienes que hacer clic en el botón de abajo y todo estará listo.</p><br>";
            $cuerpo .= "    <center><h2><a href='$url'>Activar tu cuenta</a></h2></center><br>";
            $cuerpo .= "    <p>Sí el botón no funciona, por favor haz clic en el siguiente enlace:<br><a href='$url'> $url </a>.</p><br><hr><br>";
            $cuerpo .= "    <p>Ahora el siguiente paso es hacer crecer tu negocio, estamos seguros que tenemos un plan ideal para ti. Te dejamos un enlace en donde podrás ver todos nuestros paquetes y descubrir que incluyen<br><a href='https://www.coposa.tech/es_MX/services/s.php'></a></p>";
            $cuerpo .= "  </body></html>";
            
            if(enviarEmail($email, $fullname, $asunto, $cuerpo))
            {
                
                header ("Location: signup_success");
                
                echo "<br><a href='login.php'>Acceder a tu cuenta</a>";
                exit;
                
                } else {
                $errors[] = "Ha ocurrido un error desconocido al tratar de enviar el correo electrónico.";
            }
            
            } else {
            $errors[] = "Ha ocurrido un error desconocido, por favor intenta nuevamente más tarde.";
            
            }
        }
    }
    
?>
```

**Archivo de validación de email (validate.php):**

```
    <?php 
    
    require 'conexion.php';
    require 'funcs.php';
    
    if(isset($_GET["id"]) AND isset($_GET["code"]))
    {
        
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $token = $_GET['code'];
        
        $message = validaIdToken($idUsuario, $token);
    }
    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Coincidencialmente estoy haciendo un proyecto con el mismo archivo (PHPMailer) y en la parte de envío de correos tampoco me quería funcionar, hasta que probé la recomendación de la instalación del PHPMailer con Composer [github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). Al seguir esta indicación, se genera automáticamente una carpeta llamada "vendor" y dentro de ésta, el archivo "autoload.php". Posteriormente, en el archivo "funcs.php" en la carpeta "funcs" se debe editar la función "function enviarEmail", para cargar el "vendor/autoload.php". Adicionalmente, la configuración del correo y el mensaje, se coloca dentro del "try" y no por fuera como en tu ejemplo. Con eso, ya envió el correo. Adjunto el código de la función:

`function enviarEmail($email, $nombre, $asunto, $cuerpo){

```
    require './vendor/autoload.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);


    try {
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
        $mail->Host = 'clientes.coposa.tech';
        $mail->Username   = 'no-reply@clientes.coposa.tech';  
        $mail->Password = 'JoseNFMX*1108';
        $mail->Port = 465;
    
        $mail->setFrom('no-reply@clientes.coposa.tech', 'Validador de nuevos clientes | COPOSA');
        $mail->addAddress($email, $fullname);
    
        $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
        $mail->Subject = $asunto;
        $mail->Body    = $cuerpo;
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
    
        $mail->send();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }

}`
```